# Sharing preferences across classes in android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

Hi
I am developing an android app in which
if user opens the application for first time(just installed) he gets the terms and conditions
if he accepts that he gets the registration screen
if he registers he get the login screen

however if the user exits after terms screen,again if the app is started he should get only the registration screen but not terms screen

I need two global boolean variables which can be accessed by all classes in the app
I tried sharedpreferences but I am not able to share them across classes
Anybody please throw some light.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes shared preference is correct option to share among activities in android, did u set value in sharedpreference at time user accepts terms and condition?

Comment: I defined sharedpreference in main.java where i check if terms or accepted or not. If not it goes to terms.java screen. If user clicks agree there I am editing the sharedpreferences but terms.java shows error :( tat prefs dont exit

Comment: ok, put the checkpoints now, first check in which mode u are opening? second, etSharedpreference object before using it. Third after adding value in sharedpreference commit it...  i think this should help u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the preferences using the BaseContext:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
```

from inside any Activity/Service/Receiver in your project, and you should get the same preferences: any changes you make in one class will be available to all other classes.

Answer (score 0):

retrieving a shared preference:

int mode = Activity.Activity.MODE_APPEND

```
SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS,mode);
```

// Retrieve the saved values.

termPref = sp.getString(“terms”,“”);

Answer (score 0):

You can retrive [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) in any class by passing the context. See the following example.

Get the default [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

Get your [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) with custom name

SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences_FileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);